# I am a new ubuntu 20.04 user; posting the outputs from a related question

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver, vga

```
$lspci -knn | grep -A3 -Ei "3d|video|vga"

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a78] (rev 01)

    DeviceName: To Be Filled by O.E.M.
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0a25]
    Kernel driver in use: i915

$vainfo

libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0

libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so

libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so

libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1

vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

I am not sure how to fix this, could someone please assist, thank you.

Comment: apt-file search i965_drv_video.so show two packages, i965-vai965-va-driver, and i965-va-driver-shaders.  Is either one installed?

Comment: $ locate iHD_drv_video.so
/snap/chromium/1675/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
/snap/chromium/1685/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so

Comment: $ sudo apt-file search i965_drv_video.so i965-va-driver: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
i965-va-driver-shaders: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install both packages by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe # optional - OP was able to install w/o this command
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver
```

and then run `vainfo` again.

Comment: Thanks the fix worked

Comment: Still the learning the ins and outs of this forum.  Thanks again